# Google Script Active Cell Value and MsgBox

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to get the following code to work. I want a msgbox to appear that has the value of the cell that is being edited.  This should be very simple, but I cannot get it to work.  Here is the code:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumnRow = s.getLastColumn();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editRange = s.getActiveRange();
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();
  var data = s.getActiveCell.getValue();
  Browser.msgBox(data)
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is just that you missed a pair of parenthesis after `getActiveCell`.

To help you find problems in functions that you cannot run directly (since you wouldn't get the `event` object). You can either wrap it in a try-catch, like this:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  try {
    var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var data = s.getActiveCell.getValue();
    Browser.msgBox(data)
  } catch(err) {
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

Or create the `event` object manually, and call a "test" function instead.

```
function testOnEdit() {
  onEdit({source:SpreadsheetApp.getActive()});
}

function onEdit(event) {
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var data = s.getActiveCell.getValue();
  Browser.msgBox(data)
}
```